# Add Stream name to published stream

Tags: ant-media-server-sdk

I am currently publishing a stream this way with the SDK

```
  webRTCAdaptor.publish(streamId, null);
```

Is it possible to add a stream name to a stream (apart from `streamId`) when publishing with antMedia SDK or add a name to the VOD ?

Otherwise, is it possible to retrieve a VOD stream (via the REST api) with the roomName ?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have this feature for a now. But we have some solutions for your issue. Here are the solutions:

1. You can add Broadcast in Dashboard Panel or REST API. So, You can specify the stream name you want. After that, you can stream with your created broadcast.
2. Before sending webRTCAdaptor.publish request, you can call to add broadcast REST API and you can start publishing after the response is returned from REST API request.